# Regex in Python dilemma

Tags: regex

I was having issues with previous parts of my code, but now that I fixed a few things, I can't figure out how to retrieve data and use regex correctly. I'm trying to retrieve the full address from the BBB link in the url variable. How can I pull the company name and address efficiently?

Here is the code:

```
import urllib2
import re

print "Enter an industry keyword."
print "Example: florists, construction, tiles"

keyword = raw_input('> ')

print "How many pages to dig through BBB?"
total_pages = int(raw_input('> '))

print "Working..."

page_number = 1
address_list = []

address_pattern = r'<address>(.*?)<\/address>' # here is the issue

for page_number in range(1,total_pages):

    url = 'https://www.bbb.org/search/?type=category&input=' + keyword + '&filter=business&page=' + str(page_number)
    req = urllib2.Request(url)
    req.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')
    resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    respData = resp.read()

    business_address = re.findall(address_pattern,str(respData))
    address_list.extend(business_address)

for each in address_list:
    print each

print "\n Save to text file? Hit ENTER if so.\n"
raw_input('>')

file = open('export.txt','w')

for each in address_list:
    file.write('%r \n' % each)

file.close()

print 'File saved!'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pattern must be,

```
address_pattern = r'<address>(.*?)<\/address>'
```

not `*.?`. `(.*?)` will do a non-greedy match. Get the string which exists between that tag from group index 1. Unfortunately this, won't match if there is a newline character present in the text. So I suggest you to enable DOTALL modifier.

```
address_pattern = r'(?s)<address>(.*?)<\/address>'
```

Comment: post the output of `str(respData)`

Comment: Thank you that worked! What if I was trying to get rid of an HTML comment that gets retrieved with the addresses?

Comment: HTML comment? . Post a sample data along with expected output. But I did answered your current question.

Comment: \r\n                \r\n                    <!-- 1.1.1 -->\r\n6544 Southwest Ave.<br />\r\nSaint Louis,\r\nMO \r\n63139            ' This is what I get. Not only comments but extra things in between. Also yes, thank you for answering the original question.

Comment: just remove those comments from the extracted data using `re.sub(r'<!--[^>]*-->', '', extracted_data)`

Comment: Oh okay thank you for your help. Also, I didn't downvote you? I upvoted your post. Must have been somebody else.